# Pivot a Table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to take my original query and pivot it on the SerOption column with the Value column underneath each respective SerOption. So for my example, I want "Asset Tag, "Make", "Model", "Description" and "Serial Number" as my column headers, and each [Value] in the respective column.

My original query is:

```
SELECT s.SerOption, sv.value as [Value], sv.SerialCat, sv.item, [load]  
    FROM SerialValues SV JOIN [Serialization] S on S.OID = sv.SerialCat 
WHERE [load] in (141955) 
ORDER BY item, serialCat
```

And my **attempt** at Pivoting so far is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT s.SerOption, sv.value as [Value], sv.SerialCat, sv.item, [load]  
        FROM SerialValues SV JOIN [Serialization] S on S.OID = sv.SerialCat 
    WHERE [load] in (141955) 
    ORDER BY item, serialCat
) AS serial
PIVOT
(
[Value] FOR s.SerOption in ('Asset Tag', 'Make', 'Model', 'Description', 'Serial Number')
) AS PVT
```

The error I get when trying to run this is:
*The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.*
There also appears to be a syntax error near the 'FOR' keyword.

**UPDATE**
    I have used the following updated query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT s.SerOption, sv.value as [Value], sv.SerialCat, sv.item, [load]  
FROM SerialValues SV JOIN
[Serialization] S
ON S.OID = sv.SerialCat 
WHERE [load] in (141955) 
) s
PIVOT (
MAX([Value]) FOR s.SerOption in ([Asset Tag], [Make], [Model], [Description], [Serial Number])
) AS PVT;
```

To illustrate what I'm getting now, when I ordered PVT by Item I get the following (I know I don't need the order by, its just to show that I am getting separate row values for each item):
[image]

Comment: Remove the `ORDER BY`.  That seems pretty obvious.

Comment: Why is the ORDER BY there?   what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I have removed the order by, I will update my post to show what I am getting now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I selected which items I was looking for in the outer select, and removed sv.SerialCat from the inner select. The following is the winning query.

```
SELECT [item], [load], [Asset Tag], [Make], [Model], [Description], [Serial Number]
FROM (SELECT s.SerOption, sv.value as [Value],  sv.item, [load]  
      FROM SerialValues SV JOIN [Serialization] S on S.OID = sv.SerialCat 
      WHERE [load] in (141955) 

     ) s
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value]) FOR s.SerOption in ([Asset Tag], [Make], [Model], [Description], [Serial Number])
) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT s.SerOption, sv.value as [Value], sv.SerialCat, sv.item, [load]  
      FROM SerialValues SV JOIN
           [Serialization] S
           ON S.OID = sv.SerialCat 
      WHERE [load] in (141955) 
     ) s
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value]) FOR s.SerOption in ([Asset Tag], [Make], [Model], [Description], [Serial Number])
) AS PVT;
```

It is unclear which aggregation function you want.  I chose `MAX()` as an example.

Comment: That worked, however they aren't grouped together by item number with that, so each item has a separate row for each of the 5 header values. I'm trying to format it so each item has only the 1 line with values in each of the header columns.

Comment: @Maverick . . . You have to adjust the columns in the subquery to control the rows you get -- just another reason to prefer conditional aggregation over `pivot`.